# Flutter audio_service control pause/play button not visible

Tags: flutter

I'm using audio_service and just_audio for my app and this is the source code:

```
class PAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler{
    PAudioHandler() {
        // these are used to connect just_audio with audio_service
        // audio_service is needed to control the audio in the background
        bgPlayer.playbackEventStream.map(_transformEvent).pipe(playbackState);
        _listenForDurationChanges();
        _listenForCurrentSongIndexChanges();
        _listenForSequenceStateChanges();
      }
      PlaybackState _transformEvent(PlaybackEvent event) {
        return PlaybackState(
          controls: [
            bgPlayer.playing ? MediaControl.pause : MediaControl.play,
          ],
          androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1],
          processingState: const {
            ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
            ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
            ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
            ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
            ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
          }[bgPlayer.processingState]!,
          playing: true,
          updatePosition: bgPlayer.position,
          bufferedPosition: bgPlayer.bufferedPosition,
          speed: bgPlayer.speed,
          queueIndex: bgPlayer.currentIndex,
        );
      }
}
```

However, the media control looks like this:
[image]

The pause and play buttons are not visible. There are two other interesting things about this bug. First one is that when I add

```
systemActions: const {
          MediaAction.rewind,
        },
```

It works.
[image]
The second interesting thing is that, even though the play/pause button are not visible, they are clickable: [image]
The grey circle is from me clicking the button. I searched online but I couldn't find anybody with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simulator issue. Runs properly on a real device.